# 2 subforms with same Entity with different validation Symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

In my Symfony2 Application I have a form Subscription with 2 subforms using the same Entity Address.
I'm looking for a solution to validate the 2nd form only when a checkbox is unchecked. As the subforms belong the same entity, the validation contraints are the same. The Assert\Valid entity cannont take a groups parameter, so I can"t use this solution.

SubscriptionType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('billingAddress', new AddressType())
        ->add('shippingSame', 'checkbox', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => true,
        ))
        ->add('shippingAddress', new AddressType())
    ;       
}
```

Adress.php Entity

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="line1", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $line1;
}
```

Suscription.php Entiry

```
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Shop\Address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $billingAddress;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Shop\Address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $shippingAddress;
}
```

So, I want to validate the second address only if the unmapped checkbox is unchecked.

Thanks for yout help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to work with unmapped fields is to access form data directly, and this defeats the purpose of validation. To make use of symfony's Validator component you'll have to make checkbox mapped. Just add this field to your entity, you don't have to map it to DB.

```
/**
 * @var bool
 */
private $shippingSame;

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isShippingSame()
{
    return $this->shippingSame;
}

/**
 * @param bool $shippingSame
 */
public function setShippingSame($shippingSame)
{
    $this->shippingSame = $shippingSame;
}
```

And then you can easily access it in [@Assert\Callback()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html):

```
public function validateShipping(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($this->isShippingSame()) {
        $isValid = ... ; // do the validation
        if (!$isValid) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Shipping address is not valid!')
                ->atPath('shippingAddress')
                ->addViolation();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form [Validation Groups features](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups).

You need some advanced logic to determine the validation groups (based on submitted data), you can set the validation_groups option to an array callback as follow:

SubscriptionType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

// before the 2.7 version this method is called setDefaultOptions
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            if (true == $data->shippingSame) {
                return array('validate_only_billing_address');
            }

            return array('validate_shipping_billing_address');
        },
    ));
}
```

And add the correct validation group annotation in your entity.

Hope this help. Let me know if you need more advice.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as the entity is the same for the 2 subforms, the validation groups will be the same (because defined has annotation in the Entity class), so we can't use groups_validation I think.

Comment: Hi @Nbalive16 in accordion with the doc [You can change the Groups based on the Submitted Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups) and I often use this feature. BTW the callback approach is a solution too.

Comment: Yes, we can change the group based on the data, but the groups are defined with annotation into the entity class file. As my entity (and so my fields) are the same for the 2 subforms, it's not possibile to defined and used 2 differents groups. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {

        if (true == $form->get('shippingSame')->getData()) {
            return array('validate_only_billing_address');
        }

        return array('validate_shipping_billing_address');
    },
));
```

I changed just the get() property. 
Maybe is just a version difference (honestly I didn't investigate)
actually i'm running on very last v2.7.1 .

Hope this can help someone